# Way to encapsulate methods from default.aspx.vb page to another class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oop, encapsulation

This question is about structure :

I have a Default.aspx page which holds references to (XML)services, and handles innerHTML of HTML objects. The ammount of buttons is based on services output.

Since this is an long and complex algorithm, I would like to encapsulate this in another class, to divide it into smaller and more readable chunks of code.

The problem is I do not know what the best option is, should I copy the reference of the used objects(service as well as the HTML items) into the new class ?

Since the ammount and origin of items it does not look to my like an elegant option.
I searched on the internet but could not find anything that suits this(I would think) common situation

This is the function I would like to transfer to another class. Currently it is in Default.aspx
and uses rep(ort)Service,defaultPath,path,selectionScreen and Image2 objects to draw the menu dynamically.

```
''' <summary>
''' Dynamically builds the square menu where the reports can be selected from.
''' It is based on the number of reports available
''' Show list of available reports on reporting server as HyperLinks
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Sub BuildReportSelectionArea(Optional path As String = "")

    Dim items As CatalogItem() = repService.ListChildren(path, False)
    Dim items2 As CatalogItem() = repService.ListChildren(path, False)

    'Ensure that folders are shown first
    Dim maxFolder = 0
    For i = 0 To items.Count - 1 Step 1
        If (items(i)).TypeName = "Folder" Then
            items(i) = items2(maxFolder)
            items(maxFolder) = items2(i)
            maxFolder += 1
        End If
' Some other code
End Sub

        'TODO :Ensure the alfabetical order is preserved
    Next
```

Comment: I guess it fully depends on your needs? Can you show some code? It seems your services do more than they should do, i see look & feel rather as a styling option, which you could simply extract to css, and update the xml services to rather change the class of the generated buttons? Can you give an abstraction of your code?

Comment: I pasted the code above, appreciate your help

Comment: Sorry,actually I'm not styling tchem but adding into HTML, I'll change that

Comment: as a first comment, directly writing and manipulating the innerHTML can give strange results, i would prefer in your place to use a stringbuilder or string concatination, and putting only the end result into the innerhtml

Comment: Thank you, that way I could do without passing to the class the item that has to be changed indeed and apply it on return of the string. Only I still need the repService Items Collection and path Variables to build it, so what might be a good way to pass (or maybe without passing) them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first generally comment on the code:

this means you are 2 times accessing the service, but the second array is later used to "sort" the items catalogItem, it seems a waste of resources to call the service twice

```
Dim items As CatalogItem() = repService.ListChildren(path, False)
Dim items2 As CatalogItem() = repService.ListChildren(path, False)
```

Reordering you could simply achieve using

```
    Dim items As New List(Of CatalogItem)(RepService.ListChildren(path, False))
    items.Sort(Function(item1 As CatalogItem, item2 As CatalogItem)
                   If String.Equals(item1.TypeName, item2.TypeName) Then
                       Return item1.FileName.CompareTo(item2.FileName)
                   End If
                   If item1.TypeName = "Folder" Then
                       Return -1
                   End If
                   Return 1
               End Function)
```

which would sort by folders first, then by filename (you might have to update some of your properties to match)

you could further extract by either creating a module or a shared class that accepts the repService as an attribute and the path, and returns your output code

though creating a user control / webpart so you could add this functionality to each page you would like, would be a very good option as well, and the generally accepted way to refactor complex code...

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for this kind of sorting solution but couldn't get the Sort work on this particular item group!
In this case there is only 1 webpage so no need for a webpart, still thank you very much. I will use a module or a shared class